# despite being in Date format lubridate "all formats failed to parse. No formats found" error when going from ymd to mdy

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

Edit: have been informed lubridate doesn't do any transformations.

I had a pretty straightforward variable with a YMD date with a chr format but `lubridate::mdy()` refuses to transform it into mdy (if this isn't what mdy is supposed to do, then please do suggest how to use `lubridate` to change data ordering). I truncated it to get rid of the time, and I can apply as_date to the truncated version without error, so I end up with six Date levels:

```
          .  n   percent
 2020-05-20  6 0.0400000
 2020-05-21 19 0.1266667
 2020-05-25 45 0.3000000
 2020-05-26 47 0.3133333
 2020-05-27 21 0.1400000
 2020-06-04 12 0.0800000
```

But any attempt to convert to `mdy()` *after* as_date has already been implemented using `lubridate` gets me an
`Warning message: All formats failed to parse. No formats found.`
How can this be? I've poured over previous `lubridate` posts and can't understand why a simple format change keeps failing.

I've tried base and tidyverse versions of
`test$StartDate2 <- mdy(test$StartDate2)` and they get turned to NAs

Original data `test$StartDate:  chr [1:150] "2020-05-25 16:11" ...` was truncated to `test$StartDate2:  chr [1:150] "2020-05-25" "2020-05-27"` 
and then passed through `test$StartDate2 <- as_date(test$StartDate2)` still doesn't get recognized by `mdy()`

```
test %>% mutate(StartDate3 = as_date(StartDate2),
+                 StartDate4 = ymd(StartDate2),
+                 StartDate5 = mdy(StartDate2))
# A tibble: 150 x 5
   StartDate        StartDate2 StartDate3 StartDate4 StartDate5
   <chr>            <date>     <date>     <date>     <date>    
 1 2020-05-25 16:11 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 NA        
 2 2020-05-27 6:55  2020-05-27 2020-05-27 2020-05-27 NA        
 3 2020-05-25 16:41 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 NA        
 4 2020-05-27 5:58  2020-05-27 2020-05-27 2020-05-27 NA        
 5 2020-05-26 1:28  2020-05-26 2020-05-26 2020-05-26 NA        
 6 2020-05-25 16:51 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 NA        
 7 2020-05-26 21:11 2020-05-26 2020-05-26 2020-05-26 NA        
 8 2020-05-25 16:08 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 NA        
 9 2020-05-25 14:38 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 2020-05-25 NA        
10 2020-05-26 21:56 2020-05-26 2020-05-26 2020-05-26 NA
```

Comment: Anything that is already in a `Date` or `POSIXt` class will be silently converted to `character` when you try to convert it from a string. `mdy` assumes that its strings will start with a month-like thing and end with a year-like thing, but R's default `character` representation of dates is like `2021-02-26`.

Comment: For your `StartDate` column, have you tried simply `as.POSIXct(c("2020-05-27 6:55", "2020-05-25 16:11"), format = "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")`?

Comment: <strike>Do you think that `mdy("2020-05-26")` makes sense?</strike> (That sounds harsh, reworded...) `mdy` is not *idempotent*, so it does not check to see if its input is already class `Date`. Because of this, the input is converted to string, so it sees `mdt("2020-05-26")`, where the month is last, not first, as `mdy` expects.

Comment: No, I know it's not, I'm trying to *get it into mdy*. is the idea of mdy to tell me something I can easily observe or to transform data? I have tried mdy on chr and Date versions of the data and get the same results.

Comment: The already-date-format *can* be processed with `ymd`. Note that `mdy(Sys.Date())` fails and `ymd(Sys.Date())` succeeds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the `lubridate` functions (`mdy` or `ymd` or any other) are used to change values from character type to date-type. Date types can be represented only in one-form which is `YYYY-MM-DD`. If you want dates in any other format then you can need to have values of type character. To get data in other forms you can use `format` (and not `mdy`).

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% mutate(StartDate3 = format(StartDate2, '%m-%d-%Y'))

#          StartDate StartDate2 StartDate3
#1  2020-05-25 16:11 2020-05-25 05-25-2020
#2   2020-05-27 6:55 2020-05-27 05-27-2020
#3  2020-05-25 16:41 2020-05-25 05-25-2020
#4   2020-05-27 5:58 2020-05-27 05-27-2020
#5   2020-05-26 1:28 2020-05-26 05-26-2020
#6  2020-05-25 16:51 2020-05-25 05-25-2020
#7  2020-05-26 21:11 2020-05-26 05-26-2020
#8  2020-05-25 16:08 2020-05-25 05-25-2020
#9  2020-05-25 14:38 2020-05-25 05-25-2020
#10 2020-05-26 21:56 2020-05-26 05-26-2020
```

Comment: If I'm correct, I think the "mdy" or "ymd" call is used to specify what date the format is in going into lubridate, and lubridate always spits out ymd. Is that right? I think some people get tripped up because they think the "mdy" going into lubridate is what you are telling lubridate to do, not what lubridate is trying to read?

Comment: Yes, you are right. `mdy` or `ymd` or `dmy` specifies the input type. Output type is always `ymd`.

Comment: @hachiko That is EXACTLY what happened to me.  thanks Ronak for the clarification and suggestion. It is very unusual to encounter a tidyverse package can't transform data, I just expected it to act like other tidyverse packages.

Comment: I had a feeling this was it! lubridate should just be called the ymd package